# Is putting a numpy array inside a list pythonic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to break a long sequence into sub-sequence with a smaller window size by using the `get_slice` function defined by me.
Then I suddenly realized that my code is too clumsy, since my raw data is already a `numpy` array, then I need to store it into a list in my `get_slice` function. After that, when I read each row in the `data_matrix`, I need another list to stored the information again.

The code works fine, yet the conversion between numpy array and list back and forth seems non-pythonic to me. I wonder if I am doing it right. If not, how to do it more efficiently and more pythonic?

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np

##Artifical Data Generation##
X_row1 = np.linspace(1,60,60,dtype=int) 
X_row2 = np.linspace(101,160,60,dtype=int)
X_row3 = np.linspace(1001,1060,60,dtype=int) 

data_matrix = np.append(X_row1.reshape(1,-1),X_row2.reshape(1,-1),axis=0)
data_matrix = np.append(data_matrix,X_row3.reshape(1,-1,),axis=0)
##---------End--------------##

##The function for generating time slice for sequence##
def get_slice(X,windows=5, stride=1):
    x_slice = []
    for i in range(int(len(X)/stride)):
        if i*stride < len(X)-windows+1:
            x_slice.append(X[i*stride:i*stride+windows])

    return np.array(x_slice)
##---------End--------------##

x_list = []
for row in data_matrix:
    temp_data = get_slice(row) #getting time slice as numpy array
    x_list.append(temp_data) #appending the time slice into a list

X = np.array(x_list) #Converting the list back to numpy array
```

Comment: Hm, is it possible that instead of converting, you make a wrapper/generator that acts like a list, but actually proxies access directly to the array? More devious than pythonic, but might prevent that extra 'copy' lying around.

Comment: By generator, do you mean that I should use `yield` instead of `return` in the function? For the wrapper, I am not sure how to do it...

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I mean, then the 'whole copy' won't have to sit in memory. Wrapper is just a fancy word for 'class you call that then calls the real class in a slightly different way'.

Comment: Why exactly this is a `machine-learning` or `lstm` related question? Kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this here as a semi-complete answer to address your two points - making the code more "pythonic" and more "efficient."

There are many ways to write code and there's always a balance to be found between the amount of numpy code and pure python code used.
Most of that comes down to experience with numpy and knowing some of the more advanced features, how fast the code needs to run, and personal preference.
Personal preference is the most important - you need to be able to understand what your code does and modify it.
Don't worry about what is pythonic, or even worse - numpythonic.
Find a coding style that works for you (as you seem to have done), and don't stop learning.
You'll pick up some tricks (like @B.M.'s answer uses), but for the most part these should be saved for rare instances.
Most tricks tend to require extra work, or only apply in some circumstances.

That brings up the second part of your question.
How to make code more efficient.
The first step is to benchmark it.
Really.
I've been surprised at the number of things I thought would speed up code that barely changed it, or even made it run slower.
Python's lists are highly optimized and give good performance for many things (Although many users here on stackoverflow remain convinced that using numpy can magically make any code faster).

To address your specific point, mixing lists and arrays is fine in most cases.  Particularly if

1. You don't know the size of your data beforehand (lists expand much more efficiently)
2. You are creating a large number of views into an array (a list of arrays is often cheaper than one large array in this case)
3. You have irregularly shaped data (arrays must be square)

In your code, case 2 applies.  The trick with `as_strided` would also work, and probably be faster in some cases, but until you've profiled and know what those cases are I would say your code is good enough.

Comment: Your answer has addressed most of my concerns. I am looking forward to see you full answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is very fews case where mixing list and array is necessary. You can efficiently have the same data with only array primitives:

```
data_matrix=np.add.outer([0,100,1000],np.linspace(1,60,60,dtype=int))
X=np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(data_matrix2,shape=(3, 56, 5),strides=(4*60,4,4))
```

It's just a view. A fresh array can be obtained by `X=X.copy()`.

Comment: Can you give one example when  mixing list and array is necessary?

Comment: One such example may be when you want to store a collection of `np.ndarrays` of variables types. These tools are here for you to decide when one solution is more appropriate than another. You of course have your own value hierarchy for your code, where convenience in programming may be more important to you than runtime speed or memory usage.

Answer (score -1):

Appending to the list will be slow. Try a list comprehension to make the numpy array.

something like below

```
import numpy as np

##Artifical Data Generation##
X_row1 = np.linspace(1,60,60,dtype=int)
X_row2 = np.linspace(101,160,60,dtype=int)
X_row3 = np.linspace(1001,1060,60,dtype=int)

data_matrix = np.append(X_row1.reshape(1,-1),X_row2.reshape(1,-1),axis=0)
data_matrix = np.append(data_matrix,X_row3.reshape(1,-1,),axis=0)
##---------End--------------##

##The function for generating time slice for sequence##
def get_slice(X,windows=5, stride=1):
    return np.array([X[i*stride:i*stride+windows]
                     for i in range(int(len(X)/stride))
                      if i*stride < len(X)-windows+1])
##---------End--------------##

X = np.array([get_slice(row) for row in data_matrix])
print(X)
```

This may be odd, because you have a numpy array of numpy arrays. If you want a 3 dimensional array this is perfectly fine. If you don't want a 3 dimensional array then you may want to vstack or append the arrays.

```
# X = np.array([get_slice(row) for row in data_matrix])
X = np.vstack((get_slice(row) for row in data_matrix))
```

**List Comprehension speed**

I am running Python 3.4.4 on Windows 10.

```
import timeit


TEST_RUNS = 1000
LIST_SIZE = 2000000


def make_list():
    li = []
    for i in range(LIST_SIZE):
        li.append(i)
    return li


def make_list_microopt():
    li = []
    append = li.append
    for i in range(LIST_SIZE):
        append(i)
    return li


def make_list_comp():
    li = [i for i in range(LIST_SIZE)]
    return li


print("List Append:", timeit.timeit(make_list, number=TEST_RUNS))
print("List Comprehension:", timeit.timeit(make_list_comp, number=TEST_RUNS))
print("List Append Micro-optimization:", timeit.timeit(make_list_microopt, number=TEST_RUNS))
```

Output

```
List Append: 222.00971377954895
List Comprehension: 125.9705268094408
List Append Micro-optimization: 157.25782340883387
```

I am very surprised with how much the micro-optimization helps. Still, List Comprehensions are a lot faster for large lists on my system.

Comment: list append is nearly as good as a list comprension.  `np.append` is a `concatenate`, and slow if done in a loop.

Comment: A normal python list append in a for loop is very slow, especially for large lists. List comprehensions are incredibly fast compared to a for loop list append. That's all I was trying to get at. I was not referring to np.append.

Comment: @justengel none-sense. List comprehensions are *marginally* faster than a for-loop with append. You can get them to be essentially the same speed by doing `append_to_list = mylist.append` and then using the bound method in the loop. It's a microoptimization at best

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Does it mean that my code doesn't have a huge impact in performance? Since another answer mentions that mixing list and array is rare. So I am now very confused if my code is acceptable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga See my updated answer. In practice list comprehensions are much faster for large lists.